# 2^n question (it didn't work on large numbers)

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

a power of two is a number of the form 2n where n is an integer, i.e. the result of exponentiation with number two as the base and integer n as the exponent.

i want to test a power of two number.For example if i input 128 program input should be True because 128=2^7

so i wrote this code:

```
  import math
def power_of_two(x):
  if(x==0):
      print ("False")
      return False
  else:
      n = math.log2(x)
      if n%1 > 0:
          return False
      else:
          return True
```

but in this code if i try for example 4096 it works well but if i try larger numbers,for example 4722366482869645213702 it didn't work it output True(should be False)

how can i fix this problem??

Comment: Because of float precision. Just work with integers. You can apply bitwise and `x` with `x-1` - if x is positive, it's zero only for powers of 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def power_of_two(x):
    return x > 0 and (x & (x-1)) == 0
```

Explanation.
Powers of 2 look like

```
10000000000000000000
```

After subtraction of 1 they look like

```
01111111111111111111
```

Bitwise and of these numbers is 0. For other positive numbers it's false.

Comment: how to flag true or false ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: def power_of_two(x):
    if(x==0):
        return False
    return (x & (x-1)) == 0

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to convert the number to its binary form, using `bin` then test if the first digit is a 1 and all others are 0.

```
def is_a_power_of_two(x):
  if x == 1:
    return True
  b = bin(x)[2:]
  return int(b[0]) == 1 and int(b[1:]) == 0
```

That's not very fast, but if performances are not an issue for you then it's just fine.

You can test that there are no false negatives using this:

```
for i in range(100):
  assert is_a_power_of_two(2**i)
```